# Distance between two zip codes using Google Maps API and a set of pairs of zip codes in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, google-maps, ssis

I have a set of zip code pairs in Excel. My aim is to use the Google Maps API or any other good source and get the driving distance between these zip codes for each pair. Is this possible? If these data points were in an SQL Server table, is there a way to do this using SSIS Web Services task?

I would like some pointers to how to do it best. I looked at Google Distance Matrix API but it is explicitly mentioned that using that API in a non Google Maps usage is strictly prohibited.

Thank you in advance for guiding me on how to design this.

Comment: This query was answered. I used the code snippet provided on TheAnalystCave website link provided below by TMH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Analyst Cave has a great write up on using the Google API for exactly this:
http://www.analystcave.com/excel-calculate-distances-between-addresses/

```
Public Function GetDuration(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=pl&sensor=false"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """duration"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    tmpVal = Right(objHTTP.responseText, Len(objHTTP.responseText) - InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """duration"" : {") - Len("""duration"" : {"))
    tmpVal = Right(tmpVal, Len(tmpVal) - InStr(tmpVal, """value"" : ") - Len("""value"" :"))
    tmpVal = Left(tmpVal, InStr(tmpVal, "}") - 1): tmpVal = Replace(tmpVal, ".", ",")
    GetDuration = CLng(Replace(tmpVal, ",", ""))
Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDuration = -1
End Function
```

You can then use the Google API to find more parameters:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#JSON

Comment: Please summarize or quote the relevant portion to ensure that your answer is still valid should the link expire. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: hello TMH8885, your suggestions helped out. The only change to the code on theanalyst cave is that you should use https instead of http since it returns a REQUEST DENIED error otherwise. Thank you for pointing out this resource to me.

Comment: I would also recommend getting an APi key to keep track of your API requests. came in really handy for me.

Comment: Odd, regarding the https, I never got the REQUEST DENIED using http.